# SQL Temp Tablespace is Empty

Tags: sql, oracle

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

> ORA-25153: Temporary Tablespace is Empty

I'm doing a simple SELECT OWNER FROM DBA_TABLES; query and it displays the data properly but when I try to narrow the OWNER columns down then it gives me this error.

```
SELECT OWNER 
  FROM DBA_TABLES
 WHERE OWNER = 'NAME';
```

Comment: Are you working on a slave or back-up / test environment? It sounds like someone forgot to create a temporary tablespace. Either that or someone's using up a lot of it.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm using a school provided Oracle db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is described perfectly at the following post, but if you don't have DBA rights or knowledge you won't succeed to overcome this error and I strongly suggest you to approach your DBA.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/ora-25153-temporary-tablespace-is-empty-error-in-oracle/

> The cause for the ORA-25153 error is because attempt was made to use
>   space in a temporary tablespace with no files (no datafiles defined).
>
> To solve the problem, the solution is just by adding files (datafiles)
>   to the TEMP tablespace by using ADD TEMPFILE command, or by using “Add
>   Datafiles” in Oracle Enterprise Manager.

Comment: Do you know what datafiles needs to be added?  I checked the temp tablespace and it doesn't return any rows as stated on the link that you posted so there's nothing there.

Comment: I checked the tempfile using SELECT * FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES and there is one temp file associated already.

Comment: Nvm,  I checked the guide again and made a temp tablespace and attached it to a user.

Comment: and you still get the same error? are sure? if the error is as you wrote so I don't know how to help you, sorry